# intelij f4 shortcut (jump from form to code) behaves weird

Tags: intellij-idea, shortcut

Usually when you click on a component in a form and press on F4 you jump to the component declaration in the source. This features stopped working for me and I cant figure out how to bring it back. (Sometimes it jumps to the head of the class, and sometimes does nothing). Maybe it is related to one of the side window view that is displayed? I really don't know.
It is annoying.
10x.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could be caused by some third-party plug-in. Try again with the default settings after backup and remove of [all IDEA directories](http://devnet.jetbrains.net/docs/DOC-181).

Answer (score 0):

There could be 2 reasons:

1. You might to check if you have accidentally switched the keymap. You can check it by following these steps:

   - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>`</kbd>
   - switch keymap
   - choose "default copy"
2. There could be multiple actions mapped to it (may be because of plugins). You can check the same in Settings -> Keymap -> Find actions by shortcut (icon next to search bar) -> First stroke = <kbd>F4</kbd>